# Speed up MySQL query for large database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table in my database that contain around 10 millions rows.

The problem occur when I execute this query : It takes a very long time to execute (12.418s) and I wonder how can I speed this query up.

```
SELECT *
FROM cadastre_test  
WHERE latitude >= 45.1269166 AND latitude <= 45.127816 AND longitude >= -0.6631578 AND longitude <= -0.6618832 
LIMIT 100 ;
```

I tried the BETWEEN instead of <= and >= but it was slower of 4 seconds.

Here is the CREATE TABLE query :

```
CREATE TABLE `cadastre_test` (
  `id_mutation` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date_mutation` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `numero_disposition` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nature_mutation` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valeur_fonciere` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `adresse_numero` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adresse_suffixe` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adresse_nom_voie` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adresse_code_voie` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code_postal` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code_commune` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nom_commune` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code_departement` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ancien_code_commune` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ancien_nom_commune` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_parcelle` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ancien_id_parcelle` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numero_volume` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lot1_numero` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lot1_surface_carrez` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `lot2_numero` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lot2_surface_carrez` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `lot3_numero` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lot3_surface_carrez` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `lot4_numero` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lot4_surface_carrez` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `lot5_numero` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lot5_surface_carrez` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombre_lots` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code_type_local` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type_local` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `surface_reelle_bati` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombre_pieces_principales` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code_nature_culture` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nature_culture` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code_nature_culture_speciale` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nature_culture_speciale` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `surface_terrain` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` decimal(11,7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(11,7) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: make a combine index form longitude and longitude and you should think about using spacial functions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html

Comment: Select 10 million row in 12 sec - it seems fine. But Index will work. if you see, combo index isnt working/effective, pls create separate indexes for lat and long.

Comment: If you don't need all that data, selecting individual columns can speed up your query as well -rather than selecting *

Comment: Use suitable index(s):  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add an index on your table for latitude , longitude:

```
create index inx_lang_long on cadastre_test (latitude , longitude) ;
```